# Como hacer que mi app de escritorio con Electron y node.js guarde su configuración

Tags: javascript, nodejs, electron

antes que nada, quiero comentarles que soy nuevo en este mundo, estoy por la mitad de mi carrera de desarrollador fullstack y me interesó mucho Electron, el cual estoy desarrollando mi primera app de escritorio.
La aplicacion tiene solo 2 ventanas, la primera que es la principal y la segunda que es la de configuracion (en donde se van a añadir un valor numérico y 2 path)
La funcionalidad es de ser un soft de backup que a la noche manda un directorio hacia otra pc, y al terminar apaga la maquina.
Mi duda es muy simple pero es lo que me falta para continuar, como hago para que cuando yo cierro la aplicación, todas esas configuraciones, al abrir nuevamente la app, sigan ahi guardadas? ya que en este momento cuando cierro y abro la app, todo arranca desde 0, se usa alguna base de datos? algun archivo que escriba y luego levante cuando se abre?
Muchas gracias por su tiempo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que buscas es guardar datos de forma persistente en electrón y esto lo puedes conseguir a través de [electron-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-store)

> Persistencia de datos simple para su aplicación o módulo Electron : guarde y cargue las preferencias del usuario, el estado de la aplicación, el caché, etc.

Es tan simple como utilizar el localStorage de js, tambien podrías utilizar una base de datos como SQLite pero en mi opinión electron-storage es más simple.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya me pongo a investigarlo! abrazo!

Comment: Estamos para ayudar